# Dependently typed map - can't get it wrong?

Tags: dependent-type, idris

Suppose I define my own list type.

```
data MyVec : Nat -> Type -> Type where
     MyNil : MyVec Z a
     (::)  : a -> MyVec k a -> MyVec (S k) a
```

And a `myMap` function serving as `fmap` for `MyVec`:

```
myMap : (a -> b) -> MyVec k a -> MyVec k b
myMap f MyNil     = ?rhs_nil
myMap f (x :: xs) = ?rhs_cons
```

Attempting to solve the `?rhs_nil` hole in my mind:

1. `:t ?rhs_nil` is `MyVec 0 b`
2. fair enough - I need a constructor that returns `MyVec` parameterized by `b` and I need `k` to be `0` (or `Z`) and I can see that `MyNil` is indexed by `Z` and parameterized by whatever, so I can use `b` easily, therefore `?rhs_nil` = `MyNil` and it typechecks, dandy
3. `:t ?rhs_cons` is `MyVec (S k)`
4. I need a constructor that returns `MyVec` parameterized by `b` and I need `k` to be `(S k)`

I do see that the constructor `(::)` constructs a list indexed by `(S k)` and I try to use it. The first argument needs to be of type `b` considering I am building a `MyVec <> b` and the only way to get it is to apply `x` to `f`.

`myMap f (x :: xs) = f x :: <>`

Now I get confused. The RHS of `(::)` is supposed to be `MyVec k b`, why can I not simply use the `MyNil` constructor, with unification / substitution `k == Z` (that `MyNil`) gives me, getting:

`myMap f (x :: xs) = f x :: MyNil`

I do understand that I need to recurse and have `= f x  :: myMap f xs`, but how does the compiler know the number of times the `(::)` constructor needs to be applied? How does it infer the correct `k` for this case, preventing me from using `Z` there.

Answer (score 1):

The `k` is already implied by `xs : MyVec k a`. So you cannot unify `k` with `Z` if `xs` contains some elements.

Comment: You could expand this. I think many people don't realize that `(x::xs) : Vec k a` has already been constructed by the `(::)`, therefore the `xs` is "unwrapped" from the successor, yielding a list 1 element shorter.